# Find the probability that the generations number $1,2,...,r$ will not include the progenitor, and the median distribution.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

In a population of $n+1$ people a man, the "progenitor," sends out letters to two distinct persons, the "first generation." These repeat the performance and, generally, for each letter received the recipient sends out two letters to two persons chosen at random without regard to the past development. Find the probability that the generations number $1,2,...,r$ will not include the progenitor. Find the median of the distribution, supposing $n$ to be large.

There are two people who receive the letter in the first generation. There are four people who receive the letter in the second generation, and so on. So, the number of people who receive the letter increases exponentially. A person who received the letter has ${n-1 \choose 2}$ ways to send out letters to the next generation, assuming that this person cannot send out letters to the originator. Therefore, the probability of not sending out to originator for each person is ${n-1 \choose 2}/ {n \choose 2} = 1-\frac2n$. We are asked to find the probability that 1st 2nd ... rth generations do not send out letters to the originator, and it is $\prod_{k=1}^{r}(1-\frac2n)^{2^k}$. But, the answer is $(1-2/n)^{2^r-2}$. Doesn't this answer only  consider $r-1$ th generation?

Regarding the second part of the question, I need to find $r$ such that $(1-2/n)^{2^r -2} < 1/2 < (1-2/n)^{2^r}$. I was thinking of taking logs and rearrange in some manner, but I am not sure about this. The answer is  "$2^{r+1} = 0.7n$, approximately." How can I reach this answer?

I appreciate if you give some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the simplified answer is $(1-2/n)^{2^r-2}$.

The original answer is
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{r-1} (1-2/n)^{2^k},
$$
since for generations $1,2,\ldots,r$ not to include the progenitor, the people sending out letters in generations $1,2,\ldots,r-1$ must not pick the progenitor. You do not consider where people in the $r$-th generation send their letters, since that will form generation $r+1$.

To get the simplified answer,
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{r-1} (1-2/n)^{2^k} = (1-2/n)^{\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} 2^k},
$$
and note that $\sum_{k=1}^{r-1} 2^k = 2^r-2$.

For the last part, you want to approximately solve
$$
(1-2/n)^{2^r-2} = 1/2. \quad (\ast)
$$
Write $(1-2/n)^{2^r-2} = e^{(2^r-2)\log(1-2/n)}$, and use that $\log(1-2/n) \approx -2/n$ for $n$ large (Taylor series approximation). The 0.7 will come from $\log(1/2)$ when you solve $(\ast)$.

Comment: You are right I will edit it. Thank you for your answer. For the last part, $(2^r-2) (-2/n) = log(1/2) \implies 2^{r+1} - 4 = -n 0.7$. How can I eliminate $-4$ on the left hand side and negative sign on the right hand side?

Comment: Sorry, $\log(1/2)=-0.7$, so your right-hand side is 0.7n. You then get $2^{r+1} = 0.7n-4$, at which point you can say that if $n$ is large, $-4$ is negligible, so $2^{r+1} = 0.7n$.

Comment: Also note that technically, the probability of not sending to the originator is $(n-3)/(n-1)$, since there are two people you cannot send to (yourself and the originator). However, $(n-3)/(n-1) = 1-2/(n-1)$, which we can approximate with $1-2/n$ if $n$ is large. So there are a lot of approximations being made along the way.

Comment: (I guess it doesn't say anywhere in the problem that you cannot send to yourself, but anyway.)